# Twilio Send SMS Issue (java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: text/plain; charset=UTF-8 not a supported content type)

Tags: twilio

I am fetching a problem to send SMS using Java API (version: twilio-java-sdk-3.4.0)

My java code is like

```
Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();

params.put("To", "Mobile No");
params.put("From", Constant.TWILLIO_SENDER);
params.put("Body", "My );

SmsFactory factory = twilio.getAccount().getSmsFactory();
factory.create(params); `
```

It is working fine in my local environment but fetching problem in amazon cloud

The exception is : -

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: text/plain; charset=UTF-8 not a supported content type
    at com.twilio.sdk.TwilioRestResponse.getParser(TwilioRestResponse.java:230) ~[twilio-java-sdk-3.3.15.jar:na]
    at com.twilio.sdk.TwilioRestResponse.toMap(TwilioRestResponse.java:243) ~[twilio-java-sdk-3.3.15.jar:na]
    at com.twilio.sdk.TwilioRestException.parseResponse(TwilioRestException.java:58) ~[twilio-java-sdk-3.3.15.jar:na]
    at com.twilio.sdk.TwilioRestClient.safeRequest(TwilioRestClient.java:536) ~[twilio-java-sdk-3.3.15.jar:na]
    at com.twilio.sdk.resource.list.SmsList.create(SmsList.java:68) ~[twilio-java-sdk-3.3.15.jar:na]
```

Answer (score 0):

your request seems fine.
More over if the request is working fine in your local environment, then it also means your code is good.

Things i would check,
verify the jdk version on the amazon cloud.
I personally have seen few problems with content type on amazon cloud.

your best bet would be is to check things on amazon cloud rather than your twilio java code.